# Javascript save variable to .txt file on server and overwrite the.txt content

Tags: javascript, php

I've been browsing this website and the only answers I found were for saving the variable on client side (ie using Download atribute).
In PHP, I've done this:

```
<?php
$tracktitle = "test";
$location = fopen("textfile.txt","w+");
fwrite ($location, $tracktitle);
fclose($location);
?>
```

What is the javascript equivalent of this? I want the content of textfile.txt to be deleted/replaced with the actual variable.
Let's say `var tracktitle = "test";`

I want to get some text from an HTTP page and store it in a .txt file (on FTP) then load the .txt content on an HTTPS website.
I will use chronjob to schedule this to run every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent, at least in how you're asking. Javascript is client-side; it cannot directly write to a file on a server (unless you're talking about Node, which it doesn't seem like you are). To have Javascript write a file, at best it can make a request to your server side tech (PHP in this case) with information about what to write.

Comment: What about exporting `var tracktitle` to PHP variable and use the PHP code I have above?

Comment: Once PHP hits the user, it's text. There is no PHP to write to. It's only PHP on the server side.

Comment: Found an workaround for what I wanted to acomplish. Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992871/